# Naming tab afer query export excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, rename, naming

Is there a way to add a name to the tab that the power query export table? It automatically is name sheet 1, 2, 3, etc. I would think not to use the active sheet since the active sheet would be the one I was on before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `worksheet.name`?

Comment: No code to share?